# Issue executing Selenium/C# Test script via MS Test & Command Line Arguments

Tags: visualstudio, mstest, selenium3

I have created my test script using `Selenium 3, C#` and for the browser `Firefox v49`.

When I run my test using `Visual Studio 14` it works properly and executes accordingly, but I want to use `MS Test command-line arguments` in order to run the test DLL file so that I wouldn't need to open Visual Studio to execute my test. Unfortunately when I run it off a bat file which I created for the tests, all the tests fail to execute.

My bat file script is noted below:-

```
`cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE"

mstest /testcontainer:"C:\Users\tmh\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FocusCREAnalytics\FocusCREAnalytics\bin\Debug\FocusCREAnalytics.dll`
```

`"FocusCREAnalytics.dll"` contains my test project

Can someone tell me if they have experienced a similar situation before and how they rectified it? When I check the trx file there's an error which states that the `geckodriver` does not exist, but if that's the case then how come when I run the tests through visual studios it works but not off the bat file.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the full error message. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/31021606/546871 for a possible solution.

Comment: last time i checked this doesn't work on .net core

Answer (score 1):

you do not give closing quotation marks in the second line:

`mstest /testcontainer:"C:\Users\tmh\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FocusCREAnalytics\FocusCREAnalytics\bin\Debug\FocusCREAnalytics.dll"`